# Integrate forums with OG groups?

Tags: organic-groups, users, nodes

i am using drupal 7.

I want to add forums in OG groups so that forums added in OG groups can only be accessible by members of the OG groups.

Is there any other option to grant access restriction on forms except using [Form Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access/), because it will not integrate groups with forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the module called [OG Forum D7](http://drupal.org/project/og_forum_D7). This module allow to make some forum and their topics owned by an Organic group, just like any other group content.